# Qual a origem do termo "barriga-verde" para designar alguém natural do estado de Santa Catarina?

Tags: origem, gentílicos

Para quem é natural de Santa Catarina, temos o denômino Catarinense.  Popularmente, no entanto, também temos o termo barriga-verde. Qual a origem desse termo? Foram os próprios Catarinenses que o criaram? É pejorativo?  Porque "barriga-verde"?

Comment: Se considera que a origem é militar, mas os detalhes são controversos (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barriga-verde#Origem).

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas teorias sobre a origem do termo "barriga-verde" para designar os habitantes do estado de Santa Catarina. Uma das mais difundidas é que o termo se originou no século XIX, durante a Guerra dos Farrapos, que ocorreu no Rio Grande do Sul. Na época, os soldados catarinenses que participavam da guerra usavam uniformes com calças verdes, que, devido à falta de recursos, eram feitas com tecido de qualidade inferior e ficavam desbotadas e gastas. Como resultado, as calças ficavam com manchas esbranquiçadas na altura da barriga, dando a impressão de que os soldados tinham barrigas verdes.

Outra teoria é que o termo tenha origem na pesca de tainhas na costa de Santa Catarina. Segundo essa teoria, os pescadores catarinenses usavam redes de pesca de cor verde para capturar as tainhas, o que deixava manchas verdes em suas barrigas durante o trabalho.

Independentemente da origem exata, o termo "barriga-verde" é amplamente utilizado para se referir aos habitantes de Santa Catarina, sendo considerado parte da cultura popular do estado e não é considerado pejorativo.